# Single-photon Mach-Zehnder interferometer with complete destructive interference

Tags: quantum-mechanics, interference, interferometry

[This article](https://www.lesswrong.com/posts/5vZD32EynD9n94dhr/configurations-and-amplitude) describes an experiment where you can set up a Mach-Zehnder interferometer, and send one photon through at a time, and see complete destructive interference at one of the detectors (one of the detectors detects no photons, the other detects all the photons).

I'm very conscious that that is not a scientific article, but the implications of that experiment have informed my ideas about quantum physics for a long time. However, I've looked and never seen any actual papers in trusted physics journal that unambiguously describes this experiment (along with the one in figure 3, preferably, where he blocks a path and the interference disappears) and confirms that this does indeed work even with one photon at a time.

I'd like to have confirmation and a link to such a published piece if possible.

I'd REALLY like to know if I could affordably recreate this experiment myself somehow. But that's less important than just a published piece in a respectable physics journal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but check it out:
Stable single-photon interference in a 1 km fiber-optic Mach–Zehnder interferometer with continuous phase adjustment
https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.2866

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thanks @cod3r, I think that answers the question. It goes even more specific than just the base experiment, also adding a condition that the base experiment continues to work even when the photon has to travel long distances. Interesting.